# Node spawn stdout on data not being reached when run from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sh, child-process

When the code below is run using VS Code from the Mocha-side-bar it works great.  However, when running from the command line it seems the sh.stdout.on('data'..) is reached only the first time it is run, but not again after rerunning.  It will run only one time if a new terminal is launched. In test.js:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')

const rootF = new Promise(resolve => {
  const sh = spawn('/bin/sh', undefined, {
    stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']
  })
  sh.stdout.on('data', data => {
    const dataStr = data.toString()
    console.log(dataStr)
    if (dataStr === 'password') {
      sh.stdin.write('ROOTPASSWORD\n')
      sh.stdin.write('whoami;\n')
    } else {
      resolve(dataStr)
    }
  })
  sh.on('close', code => console.log(`process exited with code ${code}`))
  sh.stdin.write('sudo -p password -S su root 2>&1 ;\n')
  console.log('SUDO SENT')
})

;(async () => {
  console.log('BEFORE')
  await rootF
  console.log('AFTER')
  process.exit()
})()
```

Command used:

```
node test.js
```

Node v 12.11.1 also Node v 13.0.1

It also appears if one just waits for a LONG time, then the command can be rerun and will work - so some background clean up is fixing the cause.

Any ideas on possible causes?

Comment: Don't really understand what is your problem. Your "or reached only once" confuses me. By the way, what `nodejs` version you have? There's a issue regarding your problem here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18446

Comment: @Jorge Fuentes González Node v12.11.1 - It may have run successfully once - but I'm not sure - the first time I ran it that test did not fail, but it did every subsequent time.

Comment: @Jorge Fuentes González can now confirm: it runs successfully the very first time I ran it but fails every subsequent time - likely some root process is remaining in memory or something?  If I start a new terminal it runs once.